# How to set dynamic fields and it values in form

Tags: angular, angular-forms, form-control, angular-formbuilder

- I'm using angular form Control.
- I have set of values to display in a form,few are static and few are dynamic.
- I'm displaying static values with formControlName and and ts file I'm
  receiving in fb group as below.

### For Known values I doing as below.

**Html File**

```
<input type = "text" formControlName="catalogItemId">
```

**Ts File**

```
this.catalog Form = this.fb.group({
catalogItemId:fb.control('').
.
.
so on
})
```

### For Dynamic values(Unknown values),I'm looping then as below(since I don't know what are fields going come here).

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let data of attributeMap | keyvalue">
     <mat-form-field>
         <mat-label>{{data.key}}</mat-label>
         <input matInput type="text" value = {{data.value}}
     </mat-form-field>
</mat-list-item>
```

Now the Question is How can I get these dynamic values in my form group(i.e this.catalog Form )

I haven't used the form builders before and I'm looking through many articles to get this doubt cleared.
Hoping a solution.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This might help https://medium.com/@krishnaregmi/how-to-create-dynamic-forms-in-angular-7-using-formcontrol-a443a2c5e3a9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *addControl()* on your form, providing it two parameters (the name of the control and the control created).
As you might want to loop over the dynamic controls only in the template, i would advice to create a nested formgroup inside your form to isolate it from the static controls of your form.

```
this.catalogForm = this.fb.group({
 catalogItemId:fb.control(''),
 dynamicControls: this.fb.group({})
});
```

```
addDynamicValues() {
 for (let key in attributeMap) {
  (this.catalogForm.get('dynamicControls') as FormGroup).addControl(key, this.fb.control(attributeMap[key]))
  }
}
```

Then in template :

```
<form [formGroup]="catalogForm">
 <section formGroupName="dynamicControls">
  <ng-container *ngFor=let control of catalogForm.get('dynamicControls').controls | keyvalue">
   <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{control.key}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" [formControlName]="control.key"
   </mat-form-field>
 </ng-container>
</section>
</form>
```

[Working example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-sample-form-addcontrols?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Hi @Gérôme Grignon,Thanks for the response,I have done the same you have given and I can populate the details successfully,but they are the patching the values, how can I do it for the dynamic values.

Comment: i don't clearly understand your question, may you try to reformulate it please?